# What to do when there's two Fk;s and either one of them is always null?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have an application that has coaches, clients and workouts.
One coach can have many clients and one client can have many coaches = many to many

One coach can create many workouts and one workout can only be created by one coach = one to many

Also, one client can create many workouts and one workout can only be created by one client = one to many

My problem here is that a workout could only be created by either a coach or a client. Not both. What’s the best way to structure the tables and fields then?

Right now I have a workout that has id: Pk, coachId: Fk, clientId: Fk. But that means that either coachId or clientId are gonna be null on every row. I guess that’s not best practice?

I’ve also thought of just having one user table with a role table connected to it. But I don’t think that’s gonna be optimal/possible since a coach and a client are gonna have many different fields and relations (eg a coach could have certificates and diplomas and a client needs to be able to be assigned to a workout).  Also a client need to be able to be assigned to one or many coaches and vice versa.

**Current design:**

```
Coach   Client  Workout         CoachClient (composite)
id      id      id              coachId Fk
                coachId Fk      clientId Fk
                clientId Fk
```

Comment: Your approach with two columns, one for each foreign key, is very reasonable.

Comment: Whoa! I disagree. It's never necessary to have nullable columns; and it's especially bad practice to have nullable Foreign Keys. I suspect inadequate analysis of `Workout`. If a `Workout` is exclusively either coach-created XOr client-created there must be something different about them. Why not have two separate tables: `CoachWorkout`, `ClientWorkout`? For example: is a `Workout` in effect a booking for room/equipment at some specific timeslot? Then put that in a `Booking` table; and create a (composite) bridge table to the owner of the booking.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path by having two separate FKs (foreign keys) on the table `workout`.

Now, to make sure only one of the FKs is always null and the other FK is always NOT null you can add a constraint:

```
create table workout (
  id int primary key not null,
  coach_id int,
  client_id int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (coach_id) references coach (id),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (client_id) references client (id),
  constraint chk1 check (coach_id is null and client_id is not null 
                      or coach_id is not null and client_id is null)
);
```

The magic is in the last constraint `chk1`. It enforces that **one and only one** of them is not null.

Comment: Good answer in general, but worth to mention that [check constraints in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) require at least version 8.0.16 to work. Older versions just ignore them.

Comment: @stickybit Duly noted, thanks. Now, if the OP has an older version, this answer won't work. And that's probably the case since MySQL 8.0 is a pretty tall order as of now, May 2019.

Comment: This solution strikes me as over-engineering, and stretching the capabilities of SQL (as @stickybit says), and giving poor performance for update. (But I'm guessing because the requirements are unclear.) I suspect it's better to create two bridge tables: `Workout-to-coach`, `Workout-to-client`;  create a view over them as project each on `Workout id`, `UNION` the two projections; make that the key of the view. Then it would be a key violation to have the same `Workout` owned by both a coach and a client.

Comment: "You are on the right path by having two separate FKs (foreign keys) on the table `workout`." I disagree, because it requires nullable Foreign Keys. Bad practice. Nullables can always be avoided. To see how: push the design to 6NF; that will reveal what's going on. (But we don't know enough from utegard's description). I am _not_ saying the eventual physical schema needs to be 6NF.

Answer (score -1):

Clients and Coaches are both Persons.  So having one table solves your FK problem.

However, if there are a lot of differences in the columns of "clients" and "coaches", then this probably cause more problems than it cures.

Please note that

- Foreign Keys have only a small number of properties; you are asking for more than they can give.
- A Foreign key implicitly creates an index, to assist with performance; you can build the `INDEX` without having an FK.
- A Foreign key is a 'constraint' that is checked at runtime.  Since your complicated check can't be handled by an FK, maybe you should abandon the FK?

Comment: We're guessing what the business requirement is here; but there seems to be a genuine need for a FK somewhere. Then we should respect that and not abandon validation. Allowing broken references into the database will end in tears; and hiding the validation in application code (which is the common recourse) is also highly unreliable. I don't so far see anything beyond the capabilities of Keys and Foreign Keys. Neither do I see anything needing nullables.

Comment: @AntC - I anxiously await seeing your Answer.

Comment: ;-) I've sketched at least two possible answers in other comments. But first I anxiously await seeing a clearer Question.